# Oracle APEX: Clearing Previous Data on Application Open

Tags: javascript

In Oracle APEX, I've created an application with a parameter-based report and added a submit button to the page. However, I'm encountering an issue: when I close and reopen the application, all the previous data remains visible. I want the regions to reset or clear every time I open the application, and I'd like the data to appear only after submitting the page with selected parameters.

The problem specifically involves persistent display of data upon reopening the application. I'm aiming for a solution where the regions are refreshed or cleared upon application load, and data is displayed only after submitting the page with selected parameters.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this behavior in Oracle APEX would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help in advance!